# Bluetooth explorer not remembering AptX selection on Macbook

Tags: bluetooth

My macbook was using the SBC codec to connect to my wireless speakers, so I used the Bluetooth explorer utility to configure "Force use of AptX". After resetting the bluetooth module, it correctly uses the AptX codec. However, the next time I connect the speakers it goes back to SBC. Is there any way to make it stick?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to tweek one setting on your Wireless speakers using the software provided by your speaker vendor.

Usually you have two modes "priority to stable connexion" (you might default to SBC here), or "priority to quality" (aptX, LDAC and high quality codecs will be higher in the preference list)

For example:

https://helpguide.sony.net/speaker/srs-xb3/v1/en/contents/TP0001029826.html